# MySQL Transaction returns error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions

So here's the stored procedure I've written. When I ran the `DELETE` and `UPDATE` in a single sql tab

as:

```
DELETE FROM curriculumsubjects WHERE curriculumId = 27;
INSERT INTO curriculumsubjects(curriculumId,subjectCode)
VALUES(27,'MATH101');
```

it works. It executes `delete` and `insert` without any problem

But if I call the stored procedure as:

```
CALL `enrollmentdb`.`updateCurriculumSubjects`(27, 'MATH101');
```

it returns the `'error'` string i put during `ROLLBACK`

**What could be causing the failure of transaction within the stored procedure body when it runs successfully if ran without stored procedure `CALL`?**

Here's the stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateCurriculumSubjects`(IN p_curriculumId int, IN p_subjectCode varchar(100))
BEGIN
    DECLARE hasError BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR sqlexception SET hasError = 1;

    START TRANSACTION;
        DELETE FROM curriculumsubjects WHERE curriculumId = p_curriculumId;
        INSERT INTO curriculumsubjects(curriculumId,subjectCode)
                                VALUES(p_curriculumId,p_subjCode);
    IF hasError THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        SELECT 'error';
    ELSE
        COMMIT;

    END IF;
END
```

By the way I'm using Mysql Workbench 6.3 and what I'm trying to do is to delete all the columns matching the curriculumId before I insert again.

On Java, I'll be iterating the call to the stored procedure for multiple inserts.

I hope you can help. I just can't find a reason why `delete` and `insert` won't work if put within a transaction.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier if you did a proper debugging and determined the exact error number in the continue handler by resignaling it.

Comment: Try removing the error handling code and run the stored procedure with only the delete/insert and see what error crops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just a mistake in your insert syntax which you have written **p_subjCode** but your input variable is **p_subjectCode** and I change Boolean type variable to tinyint(1) for more version support.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateCurriculumSubjects`(IN p_curriculumId int, IN p_subjectCode varchar(100))
BEGIN
DECLARE hasError TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR sqlexception SET hasError = 1;
START TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM curriculumsubjects WHERE curriculumId = p_curriculumId;
    INSERT INTO curriculumsubjects(curriculumId,subjectCode)
                            VALUES(p_curriculumId,p_subjectCode);

IF hasError=1 THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    SELECT 'error';
ELSE
    COMMIT;

END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't notice that. You are correct, my bad. It's just a typo error. I shouldn't have asked this. But thanks.